# VS Code sourceMapPathOverrides

Tags: visual-studio-code, source-maps

I have an Aurelia TypeScript project where my compiled JavaScript files go into the `.../wwwroot` subfolder and the original typescript files are located in `.../src`. I am trying to use the Chrome Debugger extension in VS code but breakpoints are not hit and when I turn on `diagnosticLogging` in `launch.json` the the mapped source is incorrect: It look in `.../wwwroot/src/file.ts` instead of `.../src/file.ts`.

I tried to solve this with `sourceMapPathOverrides` but with no success. It seems I cannot match my sourceRoot.

I tried this:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot",
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "/src/*": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*"     
},
```

This is the debug console output for finding the source to `login.js`:

```
›SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Reading local sourcemap file from ...\wwwroot\dist\login.js.map
›SourceMap: creating for ...\wwwroot\dist\login.js
›SourceMap: sourceRoot: /src
›SourceMap: sources: ["login.ts"]
›SourceMap: webRoot: .../wwwroot
›SourceMap: resolved sourceRoot /src -> ...\wwwroot\src
›SourceMaps.scriptParsed: ...\wwwroot\dist\login.js was just loaded and has mapped sources: ["...\\wwwroot\\src\\login.ts"]
```

Note: The three dots `...` stand for my removed path on disk to the project root.

How can I use `sourceMapPathOverrides` to have it lookup `login.ts` in `.../src/`?

---

Because of suggestion I tried to set `webRoot` to the `workspaceRoot` like this:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
```

This way the mapped source file is correct and breakpoints work. But the log also says:

> Paths.scriptParsed: could not resolve http://localhost:9000/dist/login.js to a file under webRoot: c:\Users\username\Source\Repos\myproject. It may be external or served directly from the server's memory (and that's OK).

The folder served by the webserver is the `wwwroot` subfolder in my project so from the description setting `webRoot` to `workspaceRoot` is wrong. What other problems might occur or is the suggestion of @Steffen valid?

To make sure, this is the folder structure

```
/                    (project/source/git root)
/src                 (contains typescript, html files, is sourceRoot in source mapping)
/src/login.ts
/wwwroot             (root folder served by dev web server, should be webRoot shouldn't it?)
/wwwroot/index.html  (file opened by http://localhost:9000/ which starts Aurelia bootstrapper)
/wwwroot/config.js   (SystemJS config, maps * to dist/* )
/wwwroot/dist        (folder containing compiled application files)
/wwwroot/dist/login.js
```

Comment: Have you tried `"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"` in launch.json? I'm not sure if I got your directory structure right but it should resolve your sourcemaps to `${workspaceRoot}/src/login.ts`

Comment: Hm, that way it finds the correct source map and breakpoints in VS code work. But I am not sure if other things will break. Will update the question with some of my finding, just a moment...

Comment: you're right, wwwroot should be the correct webroot of your application. but in this case /src as root of your source files is wrong. it should be ../src (relative to wwwroot). maybe you can give more details about how your source maps are generated? if you can't control the sourcemap paths, setting `"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "${workspaceRoot}/wwwroot/src/*": "${workspaceRoot}/src/*"     
}` should work.

Comment: @Steffen I gently disagree, the sourceRoot is not wrong but has to be mapped according to how I host the files in different environemnt. I think that is one of the use cases of `sourceMapPathOverrides`. I filed an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/78#issuecomment-239181420 and it looks like it works when a trailing slash is injected into *sourceRoot* in the source maps. Will do that until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in VSCode's `launch.json`

```
{
... // other bits

    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "/*": "*",
      "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    },

... // other bits
}
```