# Typescript breakpoints in Karma test don't get hit with chrome debugger in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools, karma-runner, aurelia

I have seen and read plenty of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795273/visual-studio-code-debugging-chrome-breakpoints-wont-hit) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846336/vs-code-sourcemappathoverrides) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805028/how-to-debug-karma-tests-in-visual-studio-code) their respective answers, [tutorials](http://blog.mlewandowski.com/Debugging-Karma-tests-with-VSCode.html), and the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug). However, none helped me solve my problem.

I have an Aurelia application with Typescript and Webpack. I run my tests with Karma which works just fine (including `--watch`). Now I'd like to debug my tests in VSCode. The [Chrome Debug Extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) is installed and in principle it works: I can insert `debugger;` statements so that the debugger breaks at that point.

Breakpoints, however, don't get hit. I tried both with and without source maps. My launch config looks like this:

```
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "attach to karma's chrome",
        "port": 9333,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "pathMapping": {
            "/": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "/base/": "${workspaceRoot}/"
        },
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            //"webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
            //"webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            //"webpack:///*": "*",
            //"webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
            "webpack:///myproject/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "webpack:///myproject/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
            "webpack:///myproject/*": "*",
            "webpack:///myproject/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
        },
        "trace": "verbose"
    }
```

The `webRoot` looks good to me, it's the base folder of what I can find in the source map. The `sourceMapPathOverrides` might look strange. The reason is that in the source map I find paths like `webpack://myproject/./test/unit/type-transformer/base.spec.ts`. I also tried the configuration that is commented and also without any overrides at all.

The logs say something like:

```
From client: setBreakpoints({"source":{"name":"base.spec.ts","path":"/path/to/myproject/test/unit/type-transformer/base.spec.ts"},"lines":[13],"breakpoints":[{"line":13}],"sourceModified":false})
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"setBreakpointsRequest","data":{"Versions.DebugAdapterCore":"6.6.0","Versions.DebugAdapter":"4.8.0","fileExt":".ts"}}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"verified":false,"line":13,"message":"The breakpoint will be ignored, because the generated code cannot be found (path mapping problem?).","id":1000}]}}
```

(The message is in German for me so it might not exactly match the original English message.) What I find strange is that the path on the filesystem gets sent to chrome (as `path`). No idea how it should resolve that to the correct entry in the source map.

How can I configure the debugger so that breakpoints work?